# Is it possible to change invoke frequency of touch events?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-bitmap

I'm drawing path on bitmap. While i move my finger faster it draws a long line, for example MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE occurs two times. While i'm trying to draw circular lines by moving my fingers fastly, straight lines appears. I don't want straight lines appear. I want to draw circular lines. If i move my finger slowly, action move is called more and i take good results. I want action_move event called more and more even if i move finger fastly. Is it possible to change invoke frequency of touch events? If i can do that, i can receive better outputs.

```
private Canvas canvasBitmap;
private Bitmap bitmap;  

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvasBitmap = new Canvas(bitmap);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintDraw);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                canvasBitmap.drawPath(drawPath, paintDraw);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            canvasBitmap.drawPath(drawPath, paintDraw);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: use "historical" `MotionEvent` data

Comment: something like [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/11e58d52f8d5e48409c5580252ec5326) - of course you can make it even more smooth by using `Path#quadTo` instead of `Path#lineTo` but it's a different story

Comment: no. i saved last touch points and in each move check the difference. If diffence is much, i find subpoints and join them. However, it does not solve my problem because all subpoints are on the same straight line.

Comment: so historical data is not valid? this is what you mean?

Comment: i don't need historical data in my case. Maybe making some arcs in near points can solve it but i'm not sure

Comment: i run your code, error occured while view inflating

Comment: ok wait please i will try it again

Comment: i run it again. Now it work without error. However this code does not do what i want. It draws straight lines. It has sharp corners.

Comment: yes but your code doesn't draw straight lines. Please check it. For convenience, write paths to bitmap, then in onDraw write bitmap to canvas. So all drawings will be permanenet in screen.